# Exporting data from ArcGIS for use in Fuzzy Logic in Matlab?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, matlab, fuzzy-logic

How can I export layers from ArcGIS for use in Matlab software for working with Fuzzy Logic, and what extension?

Comment: More detail would be useful, for example, what type of data are you working with?

Comment: my data are vector but i can changing them  to raster 
can you write perform individual steps of format conversion ,weighting and also make rules to me?
 
do you know what difference between SDM tools and fuzzy logic in Matlab software?
 
the other question was, should I add layers in MATLAB or should I correct inputs to name the layers in MATLAB? of the file, add input. please help me dear friend

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Matlab expects ascii rasters as input and please refer to http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-ascii.htm. Also you may need to [reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) your data to have crisp values before exporting to ascii. Lastly you would be able to do fuzzy logic analysis through [overlay toolset's fuzzy overlays](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-fuzzy-membership-works.htm).

Comment: can you write perform individual steps of format conversion ,weighting and also make rules to me?please dear

Comment: do you know what difference between SDM tools and fuzzy logic in Matlab software?

Comment: I took a course about fuzzy logic, ANN and AI, and used Matlab during that period. There was no fuzzy logic module (i.e., SDM which then adopted in ArcGIS as Spatial Overlay toolbox) for ArcGIS (I am talking about times when there were a couple of poor Internet search engines, no Google yet!). I think how you classify your data and set the rules completely depend on your question. The rudimentary workflow can be:  1. Decide factors and their crisp values (I can think of categorical sets), and then use reclassify tool to actuate these conceptualisation.

Comment: Aforementioned ArcGIS toolbox might help better in fuzzification 2. Convert ArcGIS raster to ascii (in fact with the latest additions, Matlab may process GeoTIFF as well, please research) or any other useable format for MatLab. 3. Import/load this data into MatLab and set your rules. Good luck

Comment: the other question was, should I add layers in MATLAB or should I correct inputs to name the layers in MATLAB? of the file, add input. please help me.